# Android: how to find out devices' exact pixel aspect ratio programatically?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, egl

I want to display tiles which are supposed be all squares in my Android app, using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Is it possible for an app that is installed on an Android device to find out the exact aspect ratio of the individual pixels of the device's screen programmatically without any inputs from the user?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class.  It has fields `heightPixels` and `widthPixels` which give screen dimensions, as well as other useful information like pixel density.

As mentioned in the documentation, you can get the DisplayMetrics for your device using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`

Comment: emerssso, thank you. The class seems to have the numbers I can use : 
"public float xdpi The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension"; "public float ydpi The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension."

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using the xdpi and ydpi values you get from Display.getMetrics. These values are known to be incorrect for some devices (eg. On a Huawei Ascend P1 I get xdpi and ydpi values of 152.4 and 451.6, which are definitely way off, the pixels are much more square than that). If you try to draw a perfect square based on these incorrect values, you can end up with a highly stretched rectangle on some devices. At the moment the best advice I have is to assume the pixels are square, which I understand isn't the ideal situation. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0. The Android platform code does not use these values. Instead density and densityDPI are used for both x and y coordinates. You could even try to compare your xdpi and ydpi values and if they differ significantly then default to square pixels, although I think that would also be a messy solution.